# Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with geometric distribution. Compute $P(X > n)$

Tags: probability-theory

I looked at the definition of geometric distribution and we have that $P(X = k) = pq^{k-1}$ or that written as a summation. I am unsure how to apply the inequality in a summation for $X>n$.

Answer (score 3):

Which inequality?
$$\mathbb{P}[X>n]=\sum_{m=n+1}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}[X=m]=\sum_{m=n+1}^{+\infty}pq^{m-1}=p\frac{q^n}{1-q}=q^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a geometric random variable, we are repeating identical independent trials (each resulting in failure or success) until we obtain the first success. The probability of $X>n$ is equal to the probability that the first $n$ trials are all failures.